# Skin effect - decreasing AC current part

Tags: current, conductors

The image provided by wikipedia (the black marks are mine)
[image]
explains clearly the skin effect when AC cirrent increases - the current I increases, thus H increases, and because of lenz law the eddie currents Iw are created such that the magnetic field they create will oppose the increasing H.
I couldnt understand however what happens when the current decreases - I_new is snaller than red I, thus H decreases, and it appears to me that Iwn is in the direction painted in black, therefore in the center of the wire more current flows than close to edges. How come?

Comment: It doesn't reverse direction; it just gets less.

Comment: why though? if the correct direction for the currents is as I_w, than every current loop of Iw creates a magnetic field which opposes H (the blue circle), so overall it reduces H. but as I said, the ac current is now in the decreasing part, so H decreases, so according to lenz law we should get I_wn which will increase H